# What does "吃你的豆腐" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the exact meaning of 吃豆腐, and where does the expression come from?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-%e5%90%83%e8%b1%86%e8%85%90-and-where-does-the-expression-come-from)

Someone made a joke with this phrase during dinner.

What does "吃你的豆腐" mean other than the obvious direct translation ("Eat your tofu.").